# Jumpy ListView if scrolling up

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scroll

I thought that I wouldn't be the only one with this problem, although I can't find any any solution on SO :(

**My Problem:**

I have a `ListView` with is filled with Images loaded by an ImageLoader in background. 
If I scroll down, everything works quiet well. The `getView` method is called and a new `View` is returned and hanged below the last `View`.

If I scroll up, also the `getView` method is called, as expected. But the `View`, which is created then, pusches my `ListList` down.

I don't add any Items to my `Adapter` so `getCount()` would always return the same size.

**What I tried:**

If I scroll down, and the Image is loaded into the `ImageView` I save the Height of this `ImageView` in the corresponding `Adapter` data of that Image. If I scroll up, and a Height of the `Adapter` data is set, I set the Height of the `ImageView` in the `getView` method. See code below:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View vi=convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;
    final Image img = data.get(position); // data always same size

    if(convertView==null){
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_new_posts, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        // ....

        vi.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    }
    //**Try to set the right size of the ImageView before the parent view is created**
    if(img.getHeight() != 0 && img.getWidth() != 0){
        holder.image.getLayoutParams().height = img.getHeight();
        holder.image.getLayoutParams().width = img.getWidth();
        holder.image.requestLayout();
    }

    // ....

    //**Load Image asynchronously**
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(url, holder.image);
  return vi;
}
```

But this approach had no effect.. it still jumps if I scroll up.

Any Ideas?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a placeholder image while the actual image loads.

Or

Set width and height of imageview in dp in layout